# Problem while messing with ENUM on a rover project

Tags: python, class, oop, enums

```py
class Compass(Enum):
    NORTH = (0, 'N')
    WEST = (1, 'W')
    SOUTH = (2, 'S')
    EAST = (3, 'E')
    def __init__(self, id, shortname):
        self.id = id
        self.shortname = shortname

    @staticmethod
    def tovalue():
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, Compass))

    @staticmethod
    def tolist():
        return list(map(lambda c: c.shortname, Compass))

    @staticmethod
    def toint():
        return list(map(lambda c: c.id, Compass))


    def succ(self):
        int_list = Compass.toint()
        max_int = max(int_list)
        min_int = min(int_list)
        v = self.id +1
        if v > max_int:
            v = self.id = min_int

        for thing in self.tovalue():
            if v in thing:
                return thing


class Rover:

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, compass):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.compass = compass
        for thing in Compass.tovalue():
            if self.compass in thing:
                self.compass = Compass(thing)


        compass_pairs = Compass.tovalue()




    def left(self):
        new_compass = Compass((self.compass.succ()))
        self.compass = new_compass
```

```py
a = Rover(1,2,'N')
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
a.left()
print(a.compass)
```

So basically I create a rover here
and turn it left
So 4 turns naturally bring you back to the starting direction
Which is North in this case
The code works for the first 4 turns
But the next cycle it fucks up for some reason

```
Compass.NORTH
Compass.WEST
Compass.SOUTH
Compass.EAST
Compass.NORTH
Compass.WEST
Compass.SOUTH
Compass.NORTH
Compass.WEST
```

this is the result of the prints
The first north is not a turn its the staring position
So it should've been South to east but its south to north

Comment: When you inspected/printed values and/or conditions at various points in your program was there an obvious place where it was misbehaving?
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I use pycharm, I tried printing key conditions and the thing that was messed was the int list i think, When N was entered the list would go [3,1,2,3] so the min would become 3.

Answer (score 1):

The *problem* occurs because you set the id attribute to zero with

```
    if v > max_int:
        v = self.id = min_int
```

Don't set the id attribute when *rolling over* from east to north.

```
    def succ(self):
        int_list = Compass.toint()
        max_int = max(int_list)
        min_int = min(int_list)
        v = self.id +1
        if v > max_int:
            # v = self.id = min_int
            v = min_int

        for thing in self.tovalue():
            if v in thing:
                return thing
```

---

```
a = Rover(1,2,'N')
print(a.compass,a.compass.id)
for _ in range(15):
    a.left()
    print(a.compass,a.compass.id, end='| ')
```

---

```
Compass.NORTH 0
Compass.WEST 1| Compass.SOUTH 2| Compass.EAST 3| Compass.NORTH 0| Compass.WEST 1| Compass.SOUTH 2| Compass.EAST 3| Compass.NORTH 0| Compass.WEST 1| Compass.SOUTH 2| 
Compass.EAST 3| Compass.NORTH 0| Compass.WEST 1| Compass.SOUTH 2| Compass.EAST 3|
```

Comment: Oh my god THANK YOU, thats why it only broke when it hit the minimum this makes so much sense. I realised it was that part of the code that was the problem but didnt understand why it changed the enumid but now it makes so much sense!